# echo in different colour for Mac terminal

Tags: macos

This code is expected to change the terminal output colour to yellow but it is giving the unexpected results as shown.
Any idea why and how to fix it so that it gives the output in yellow colour?

```js
demo$YELLOW_F="\033[33m";
demo$echo "${YELLOW_F}man"
\033[33mman
demo$
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to tell `echo` to interpret escape characters with `-e` switch:

```
echo -e "${YELLOW_F}man"
```

[image]